# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]} = \lbrace a + b\sqrt3: a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]} = \lbrace a + b\sqrt3: a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$

My answer:

Must show:

i) $0 \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

ii) $1 \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

iii) $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

iv) $xy^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

Showing:

i) $ 0 = 0 +  0\sqrt3 \implies 0 \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

ii) $ 1 = 1 +  0\sqrt3 \implies 1 \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

iii) Let $x = a + b\sqrt3$ and $y = c + d\sqrt3$

$\implies x-y = a - c + (b - d)\sqrt3$ which has the form $x + y\sqrt3$ 
then $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}{[\sqrt3]}$

iv) $xy^{-1} = (a + b\sqrt3)(c + d\sqrt3)^{-1}$

I don't know how to finish. Finding the inverse of second term and equaling to 1?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Also, typically the ring (or field after this proof) is written $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ without it subscripted.

Comment: You could have used that $x^2 - 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. And therefore the  quotient $\frac{\mathbb Q[x]}{\langle x^2 - 3\rangle}$ is a field. Through the surjective homomorphism $$\begin{align}\phi : \mathbb Q[x] &\to \mathbb Q [\sqrt 3]\\f(x) &\mapsto f(\sqrt 3)\end{align}$$ you would have that quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3]$. As the former is a field your result follows.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt3}=\frac{a-b\sqrt3}{(a+b\sqrt3)(a-b\sqrt3)}=A+B\sqrt3.$$

Comment: I'm lost, still can't see.

Comment: What is $(c+d\sqrt3)\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt3}$? Is it of form $x+y\sqrt3$?

Comment: Finding the inverse hinges on the following fact: $(a + b\sqrt{3})(a - b\sqrt{3}) = a^2 - 3b^2 = q \in \Bbb Q$. Now, if you can prove that for $a,b \in \Bbb Q$, that $a^2 - 3b^2 = 0$ if and only if $a = b = 0$, it follows that if $a + b\sqrt{3} \neq 0 = 0 + 0\sqrt{3}$, we can divide my first equation by $q$-to get: $(a + b\sqrt{3})(1/q)(a - b\sqrt{3}) = q/q = 1$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Didn’t you see the technique of Rationalizing the Denominator in high school?